# Is there a way to control the order of message handlers when using polymorphic messages in NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus

We have two message types `UpdateIndividual` and `UpdateIndividualWithDetails`.  `UpdateIndividualWithDetails` inherits from `UpdateIndividual`.  We then have handlers for each and we're specifying the order with

```
public void SpecifyOrder(Order order)
{
    order.Specify(new First<UpdateIndividual>());
}
```

This doesn't work, as the `UpdateIndividualWithDetails` always gets called first.  We're using NServiceBus 2.6 and can't upgrade right now.  Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: It may be the simplest to just target the lowest level types in your message handlers.

Comment: Can you remove the inheritance? That is what is confusing NServiceBus about the intended order.

Comment: @UdiDahan We need both messages to run the handler for the base type, and then we need extra processing for the inherited type.  I thought that was the point of the polymorphic handlers, so you could extend functionality?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you included in the question it seems that you accidentally specified a message type instead of a handler type.

If you have separate handler types, e.g. `UpdateIndividualHandler` and `UpdateIndividualWithDetailsHandler`, for each form of the message, I'd be surprised if this didn't work:

```
public void SpecifyOrder(Order order)
{
    order.Specify(new First<UpdateIndividualHandler>());
}
```

alhtough it's been a while since I looked at NServiceBus, so I may not be right.

Comment: No that's the name of the handler, poorly named I realise

Comment: So the handler for `UpdateIndividual` is also called `UpdateIndividual`? You must have some funny using statements at the top of that code file ;) are you sure you didn't specify the message type by accident as the type parameter?

Comment: :) No, definitely the handler, the messages namespace isn't there

Answer (score 0):

Using composition, rather than inheritance solved our issue.